# Why to assign prototype to itself

Tags: javascript, flux

I found an interesting use case of Object.assign in Flux's documentation, example of Dispatcher in its architecture:

```
var assign = require('object-assign');

var _callbacks = [];

var Dispatcher = function() {};
Dispatcher.prototype = assign({}, Dispatcher.prototype, {
    register: function(callback) {
        _callbacks.push(callback);
        return _callbacks.length - 1; // index
    }
});
```

Source: http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-a-dispatcher

What's the reason of assigning an extended prototype to the same object's prototype?

Comment: if you do it like that, it does not modify the prototypes of the objects which were created with "new Dispatcher()" before the assigment has been done. I guess it follows the "immutability" -idea, preserving also the original prototype functions, small test here http://jsfiddle.net/uxfr8bea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that they just wanted to extend prototype. When [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (npm `object-assign` is a pollyfill) is used like this:

```
assign({}, Dispatcher.prototype, {/* ... */});
```

it returns a new object, result of extension of `Dispatcher.prototype` (properties from prototype are copied to new object), however original `Dispatcher.prototype` is *not affected*. So in order to actually extend it they had to reassign prototype altogether with the new extended object.

However it would make more sense to avoid confusing assignment:

```
assign(Dispatcher.prototype, {/* ... */});
```

Above would just extend prototype without need of reassignment.

Comment: To clarify: there's no `... =` before that second `assign` example. That might not be clear when comparing to the first.